# Having a nested item id and owners id, find out if the item belongs to that owner

Tags: sql, postgresql

This table is called category:

```
id|template_id|name    |entry_count|is_base_template|can_rename|can_delete|section|userId|parentCategoryId|
--|-----------|--------|-----------|----------------|----------|----------|-------|------|----------------|
 1|           |ToDo    |          0|true            |true      |true      |A      |      |                |
 2|           |Notes   |          0|true            |true      |true      |A      |      |                |
 3|          1|ToDo    |          0|false           |true      |true      |A      |     1|                |
 4|          2|Notes   |          0|false           |true      |true      |A      |     1|                |
 5|           |my todos|          0|false           |          |          |A      |      |               3|
 6|          1|ToDo    |          0|false           |true      |true      |A      |     2|                |
 7|          2|Notes   |          0|false           |true      |true      |A      |     2|                |
```

Each category can have children, it's possible to determine whether we're dealing with a category or subcategory by the field called `parentCategoryId`, it's `NULL` for categories and is not `NULL` for subcategories.

I know `userId` and category id which is simply `id` in that table. I have to find out if a category with certain id (id = 5 for example) belongs to a certain user (with id = 1, e.g.).

There must be some trick to do this, but I can't think of one.

My version of PostgreSQL is `12.3`.

**EDIT-1**:

First of all, thanks.

I tried executing it in my local client (DBeaver) and also in the console, and it won't work. I've just changed demo to category:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, userId, parentCategoryId
    FROM category
    WHERE id = 5 --the category of interest

    UNION

    SELECT d.id, d.userId, d."parentCategoryId"
    FROM category d
             INNER JOIN cte ON d.id = cte."parentCategoryId"
)
SELECT TRUE
FROM cte
WHERE userId = 1 --the user of interest
LIMIT 1;
```

I'm getting an error saying this:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "userid" does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "category.userId".
  Position: 40
```

**EDIT-2**:

If I fire off this line

`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'category';`

The result I get looks like so:

```
column_name     |
----------------|
parentCategoryId|
template_id     |
userId          |
id              |
entry_count     |
is_base_template|
can_rename      |
can_delete      |
name            |
section         |
```

Comment: So Svetlin Zarev was right, your columns are case sensitive. (There is probably some setting in typeorm to prevent this from happening.) When using `userId` and `d.userId` in your query, the DBMS looks for a column called `userid`, but there is only `userId`. Use double quotes hence to access the column: `"userId"` and `d."userId"`.

Comment: Oh I see, okay, I will try.

Comment: It seems that typeorm always escapes the column names, but fortunately, it can be disabled: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/defa9bced0b5d1258e4f50d5c590978e6d3324d3/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts#L470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo data:

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
    "id"               INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "name"             TEXT    NOT NULL,
    "userId"           INTEGER NULL,
    "parentCategoryId" INTEGER NULL,

    CONSTRAINT category_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT cateory_fkey_parent_id FOREIGN KEY ("parentCategoryId") REFERENCES category (id)
);

INSERT INTO category(name, "userId", "parentCategoryId")
VALUES ('ToDo', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO category(name, "userId", "parentCategoryId")
VALUES ('Notes', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO category(name, "userId", "parentCategoryId")
VALUES ('ToDo', 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO category(name, "userId", "parentCategoryId")
VALUES ('Notes', 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO category(name, "userId", "parentCategoryId")
VALUES ('my_todos', NULL, 3);
INSERT INTO category(name, "userId", "parentCategoryId")
VALUES ('ToDo', 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO category(name, "userId", "parentCategoryId")
VALUES ('Notes', 2, NULL);
```

You can use a recursive query to find the parent tree of your category, then you can check if the user owns any of the parent nodes:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT "id", "userId", "parentCategoryId"
    FROM category
    WHERE id = 5 --the category of interest

    UNION

    SELECT d."id", d."userId", d."parentCategoryId"
    FROM category d
             INNER JOIN cte ON d."id" = cte."parentCategoryId"
)
SELECT TRUE
FROM cte
WHERE "userId" = 1 --the user of interest
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that all column names are quoted - that means that they are case sensitive.

How the query works:

The recursive query contains tree parts:

1. The base of the query (non-recursive), which retrieves some rows
2. UNION clause, which combines the results from the recursive and non-recursive parts
3. A recursive part, which is executed for each row returned from both the recursive and non-recursive parts.

In your sample data, the base of the query returns the row `(id=5, user=null, parentCategoryId=3)`. This row is passed as input to the recursive query, which joins it with the `category` table. The other query returns a new row `(id=3, userId=1, parentCategoryId=null)`. Again this row is passed as an argument to the recursive query, but as `parentCategoryId=null`, this time the query does not return any rows, and as a result the execution is terminated. The `UNION` clause combines the two rows into one resultset. Now the outer `select` checks if any of the returned rows contains `userId=1` and returns TRUE in that case.

Comment: Would you please check the EDIT in the question? I could not run the script, it yielded an error and I described it there. Even though it runs smoothly on fiddle.

Comment: @Albert Try removing the quotation marks around the columns. You do not need to quote them

Comment: Ah actually DBeaver does this, I removed the quotation but nope, it didn't help =( still the same error.

Comment: @Albert Can you please run `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'category';` ? I suspect that you have created your tables using the double quotes, which means that they are **case sensitive**. You have two options - if you can recreate the tables without the double quotes - it will save you from a lot of trouble in the future. The other option is to quote every single column/table and make sure that you are using the correct capitalization - ugh

Comment: Hmmm well I'm actually using typeorm, and in this case typeorm is responsible for creating tables. So the quotation marks are used in case table/column names are case sensitive, right? I'm not sure about the way typeorm does it...

Comment: Oh and I've run the script and reported the result in my EDIT-2 in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @Albert I've updated my answer, you just need to quote the columns

Comment: It would be great though if you would elaborate a little more on how this query works.